# Backend user view own articles

Tags: administrator

I need to provide access through joomla 3.6 backoffice to different groups of users: they must be able to SEE, create and edit only their categories and their articles.
How can I do? With the ACL system I can only avoid that they can modify the items but can still see them.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

With **[ACL Manager](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/acl-manager/)** (paid extension), you can use its enhanced ACL feature (from its options), to show only editable articles and modules to your users.

From the features description of the component:

> **Enhanced Joomla ACL**
>
> A selection of powerful additional ACL features on top of the Joomla
>   ACL system like: Permissions per Module, Show Editable Modules only,
>   Show Editable Articles only and Permissions for the Category Manager.

Comment: I love ACL Manager and install it on every site I build.  Definitely worth the money.